# How to define a function macro to check key between multiple localized string files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, localization, macros

I have a `Localizable.strings` file for my project's i18n, and a lib uses `KYLocalizable.strings`.

I have considered to make `Localizable.strings` "subclass" from `KYLocalizable.strings`, but it cannot as far as I know. So instead, I want to define a function macro like what SDK does:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
#define NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, tbl, comment) \
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:(tbl)]
```

Pseudo code：

```
#define CustomLocalizedString(key, comment) \
    // if key exists in Localizable.strings
    //   use it
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
    // else
    //   search it in KYLocalizable.strings
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:@"KYLocalizable"]
```

so I can just use `CustomLocalizedString(<key>, <comment>)` in my project.
But how to check whether the key exists in `Localizable.strings` or not?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the key doesn't exist, the string you will receive will be the key itself.
So as long as you suppose you will never use the key as a localized string, you can test if NSLocalizableString returned you the key or not.

Answer (score 6):

In this call:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

The **value** parameter (currently an empty string) will be used if a string can't be located in your strings file using the specified key.  So... all you should need to do is place your second lookup to *KYLocalizable.strings* as the value to that parameter.  The code would look similar to this (I didn't actually run this, but it should be close):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) 
    value:[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:@"KYLocalizable"]
    table:nil]
```

At that point, the string in *Localizable.strings* will be used if found. Otherwise, the value in KYLocalizable.strings will be used.  If it isn't found either, then a blank string will be returned (since that is what is specified in the nested **value** parameter).

However, one inefficiency of this approach is that your application will actually attempt the lookup in KYLocalizable.strings first on every attempt (so that this result can subsequently be passed in as the **value** parameter when doing the outer lookup to *Localizable.strings*).  If you actually want to check *Localized.strings* first, and then *only* do a second lookup if the string isn't found, I think you'd need to create a method with that logic in it (for example, add a method in a category on NSBundle).

Comment: The lack of efficiency bums me out, but as the place I'm using this code isn't fired often (it's only for errors), it'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Xval, I've just figured it myself and here's a simple function (please offer some suggestions if you have a better idea):

```
#define KYLocalizedString(key, comment) \
  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:nil table:nil] isEqualToString:(key)] ? \
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:@"KYLocalizable"] : \
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

`localizedStringForKey:` will return a NSString that as @Xval said. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```
var key = "your_key"
NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey(key,
                                             value: NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey(key, value:"", table: nil),
                                             table: "Your_Custom_Localizable_File")
```

Just to clarify things, according to Apple's documentation:

```
If key is not found and value is nil or an empty string, returns key.
```

So using this technique you can nest calls to as many localization files as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this handy extension for localized strings, so you can just use the `localized()` function to get the localized string(you can also pass arguments) and the `isLocalized` computed property to check whether the string is localized or not:

```
extension String {

    var isLocalized: Bool {
        return localized() != self
    }

    func localized(parameter: CVarArg? = nil) -> String {
        if let parameter = parameter {
            return String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), parameter)
        }
        else {
            return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
        }
    }

    func localized(parameter0: CVarArg, parameter1: CVarArg) -> String {
        return String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), parameter0, parameter1)
    }

}
```